# PHP MySQL - INSERT INTO SELECT sequential

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need some help to do php script. Alright, I need to populate a new table **PIVOTrun** from another table called `runtable`. I can do it with no issues when I know column names. My goal is is generate a generic script with does in sequential wat this insert into select. My big issue, I don't manage to trim column name and generate the correct generic sql query in my php script.

**My PIVOTrun table has this structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE PIVOTrun (`ID` varchar(10), `Reference`varchar(6), `Variant` varchar(6), `ComputeVariant` varchar(20),`HGVSvar`varchar(50), `ProtDesc` varchar(50), `a combined %` decimal(5,2),`a combined of` int (4), `a forward %` decimal(5,2), `a forward of` int(4),`a reverse %` decimal(5,2), `a reverse of` int(4),
`b combined %` decimal(5,2),`b combined of` int (4), `b forward %` decimal(5,2), `b forward of` int(4),`b reverse %` decimal(5,2), `b reverse of` int(4)                      
)
```

**Here's a sample of my runtable:**

```
Reference   Variant     3SA46FEDa combined %    3SA46FEDa combined of   3SA46FEDa forward %     3SA46FEDa forward of    3SA46FEDa reverse %     3SA46FEDa reverse of    3SA46FEDb combined %    3SA46FEDb combined of   3SA46FEDb forward %     3SA46FEDb forward of    3SA46FEDb reverse %     3SA46FEDb reverse of    34S06MILa combined %    34S06MILa combined of   34S06MILa forward %     34S06MILa forward of    34S06MILa reverse %     34S06MILa reverse of    34S06MILb combined %    34S06MILb combined of   34S06MILb forward %     34S06MILb forward of    34S06MILb reverse %     34S06MILb reverse of    
ALKe23          38:T/C          0.00                    408                     0.00                    166                     0.00                     242                     0.00                   169                     0.00                     44                     0.00                    125                     0.00                     2355                   0.00                    991                     0.00                    1364                    0.00                    1525                    0.00                    555                     0.00                    970
ALKe23          168:G/A     35.78               408                     31.33               166                     38.84                    242                     53.25                  169                     47.73                    44                     55.20                   125                     0.00                     2355                   0.00                    991                     0.00                    1364                    0.00                    1525                    0.00                    555                     0.00                    970
```

So to populate my PIVOTrun table, I do:

```
insert into PIVOTrun SELECT '3SA46FED',`Reference`,`Variant`,`ComputeVariant`,`HGVSvar`,`ProtDesc`,`3SA46FEDa combined %`, `3SA46FEDa combined of`, `3SA46FEDa forward %`, `3SA46FEDa forward of`, `3SA46FEDa reverse %`, `3SA46FEDa reverse of`, `3SA46FEDb combined %`, `3SA46FEDb combined of`, `3SA46FEDb forward %`, `3SA46FEDb forward of`, `3SA46FEDb reverse %`, `3SA46FEDb reverse of` FROM run09022016

insert into PIVOTrun SELECT '34S06MIL',`Reference`,`Variant`,`ComputeVariant`,`HGVSvar`,`ProtDesc`,`34S06MILa combined %`, `34S06MILa combined of`, `34S06MILa forward %`, `34S06MILa forward of`, `34S06MILa reverse %`, `34S06MILa reverse of`, `34S06MILb combined %`, `34S06MILb combined of`, `34S06MILb forward %`, `34S06MILb forward of`, `34S06MILb reverse %`, `34S06MILb reverse of` FROM run09022016
```

I need to find a way to generate in sequential and generic way those queries.
What I tried in PHP is:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

//Get column names
$resultShowCol = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW COLUMNS FROM run09022016");


if (mysqli_num_rows($resultShowCol) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultShowCol)) {
        $columns[] = $row['Field'];

    }
    foreach($columns as $cell)
        $out=substr($cell,0,strpos($cell, "a combined of"));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO PIVOTrun SELECT '.$out.' ";
foreach($columns as $ind=>$val){


        $sql .= $val.",";


}
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
$sql .= ' FROM run09022016';
echo $sql;
?>
```

But I don't manage to substring the interested row and I don't manage to generate sequentialy the query. I have all the fields which arrive in my query. Does anybody know how to do it? Hope someone could help me.
Many thx to have pay attention to my post.